# How to write (SetValues) to a Google Sheet using a filtered forEach loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, filtering

I've been trying for hours to make the following Google Apps Script work. What it needs to do, is send emails (from an html-template) to anyone that:

- has a complete Event Schedule (which is completed if they have been
  assigned to at least 4 events, which is counted in column Q);
- has NOT been sent an email earlier (which is kept track of in column
  R);

The script keeps track of errors in column S, i.e. if there's no email address provided.

It appears it only works:

- if I comment out

  data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[17] == true & r[16] > 3});
- or if I comment out

  ws.getRange("S3:S" + ws.getLastRow()).setValues(errors);
  ws.getRange("R3:R" + ws.getLastRow()).setValues(mailSucces);

How can I get this script to work properly?
A copy of the Google Sheet I'm referring to is this one:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sbOlvLVVfiQMWxNZmtCLuizci2cQB9Kfd8tYz64gjP0/edit?usp=sharing

This is my code so far:

```
function SendEmail(){

  var voornaam = 3;
  var achternaam = 4;
  var email = 5;
  var event1 = 9;
  var event2 = 10;
  var event3 = 11;
  var event4 = 12;
  var event5 = 13;
  var event6 = 14;
  var event7 = 15;
  
  var emailTemp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email");
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Events Day 1");
  
  var datum = ws.getRange(1,3).getValue();
  var spreker = ws.getRange(1,6).getValue();

  var data = ws.getRange("A3:R" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();

  data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[17] == false && r[16] > 3}); //Either this needs to be commented out...

  let errors = [];
  let mailSucces = [];
  data.forEach(function(row){
    try{
      emailTemp.voornaam = row[voornaam];
      emailTemp.email = row[email];
      emailTemp.datum = datum;
      emailTemp.spreker = spreker;
      emailTemp.event1 = row[event1];
      emailTemp.event2 = row[event2];
      emailTemp.event3 = row[event3];
      emailTemp.event4 = row[event4];
      emailTemp.event5 = row[event5];
      emailTemp.event6 = row[event6];
      emailTemp.event7 = row[event7];
        
      var htmlMessage = emailTemp.evaluate().getContent();
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
        row[email], 
        "Here you go! Your personal schedule for the event of " + datum, 
        "Your emailprogramm doesn't support html.",
        {
          name: "Event Organisation Team", htmlBody: htmlMessage, replyTo: "info@fakeemail.com"
        });
        errors.push([""]);
        mailSucces.push(["TRUE"]);
    }
    catch(err){
      errors.push(["Error: no message sent."]);
      mailSucces.push(["False"]);
    } 
  }); //close forEach
    
  ws.getRange("S3:S" + ws.getLastRow()).setValues(errors);  //or this and the next line need to be commented out.
  ws.getRange("R3:R" + ws.getLastRow()).setValues(mailSucces);
}
```

**Edit** I have been trying and thinking en trying... but still haven't found out how to make it work. But I also got understanding of why it's not working; I just don't know how to get it fixed.
Let me elaborate on the problem a bit more:
The problem is, that within the `forEach` loop the range is a filtered variant of the data, pulled from the spreadsheet with `getValues`. Therefore, writing data back with `ws.getRange("R3:R" + ws.getLastRow()).setValues(mailSucces);` results in mismatched checkmarks in te spreadsheet.
So, somehow I need to put *the range* of the previous used filter `data = data.filter(function(r){ return r[17] == false & r[16] > 3});` in a variable...? I guess?

Furthermore, I don't think it's wise to use `setValue` within the loop, because (from what I understand from my searching on the topic) this results in a slow script, because every loop the script makes an API call to write in the spreadsheet. Hence the `errors.push` and `mailSucces.push`, and my attempt to do a setValue at the end, after the loop is finished.

Can someone help me to finish this problem?

Comment: *"if I mention out"* Do you mean [*comment out*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comment_(computer_programming)#Debugging)?

Comment: yes! I'm sorry. Fairly new to this 

Comment: By the way: the error message I get is:  
__Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 18.
SendEmail @ code.gs:54__

Comment: In what line are you getting that exception?

Comment: @Aerials the Exception is in line 54, like I pasted above. That’s  the second to last line of code, starting with _ws.getRange_
The exception is already solved by Milan but the writing of the data in the sheet to keep track of emails sent and error messages, are still getting 1 row off for each cell without an email address. So the amount of cells off increases every cell that misses an email address. 
Filling empty cells with placeholder data would solve that problem, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is different size of the **range** you write to and **data** you are writing in.

Try replacing:

```
ws.getRange("S3:S" + ws.getLastRow()).setValues(errors);
ws.getRange("R3:R" + ws.getLastRow()).setValues(mailSucces);
```

With:

```
ws.getRange(3, 19, errors.length, 1).setValues(errors);
ws.getRange(3, 18, mailSucces.length, 1).setValues(mailSucces);
```

You should use this variation of **getRange**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns

Your data has non-fixed number of rows and fixed number of columns (1). In general case your data will be matrix of X rows and Y columns. For that purpose you can make it completely dynamic:

```
sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, data.length, data[0].length)
```

Just make sure data.length is > 0 before you do this, otherwise data[0].length will break.

---

**Edit:**
I started writing a comment but it got too long. There are couple of things that may go wrong with sending emails. First thing I noticed is that you use **&** in filter, but in AppsScript/JavaScript/C-like-languages, you should use **&&** for logical AND. Now the email: you only detect the code break with the catch block. At this point you don't know why the code breaks it could be anything. With GmailApp I recommend you to use createDraft while developing, then when all ok replace it with sendEmail for the final version, both functions have the exact same parameters, thank you Google devs ;-).

To find out the exact problem you should get the error message on break and display it. *err.stack* should tell you pretty much everything:

```
catch(err){
  Logger.log(err.stack); // Added
  errors.push(["Error: no message sent."]);
  mailSucces.push(["False"]);
}
```

Run the *sendEmail* function from the code editor and you should see the Log for each catch(err) pass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Milan!! I've replaced the lines with your suggestions and the error messages stopped. Also, the right people got the email: [Peter Costello and Elvis Presley](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sbOlvLVVfiQMWxNZmtCLuizci2cQB9Kfd8tYz64gjP0/). But the output in [the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sbOlvLVVfiQMWxNZmtCLuizci2cQB9Kfd8tYz64gjP0/) was put in the wrong row: 1 row too high in the first, and 2 rows too high in the second... Therefore, Peter and Elvis keep getting the same emails.

Comment: Furthermore, I'm still trying to wrap my head around your suggestion about making the whole script dynamic... don't understand it yet, and have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for thinking with me Milan! I’ll change the & in && right away (it worked nevertheless: pretty clever).

Comment: I’ll use your valuable advice to use createDraft: that way I can test it on the real worksheet: sweet! And it also saves for my daily quota that can be send with a script :-). For the catch error part: I'll use your logging tip to get an understanding of the data.

Comment: I start to understand why the check marks and error message end up in the wrong location in the spreadsheet: the setValues are pushed outside of the forEach loop en in the _complete worksheet_, while the forEach loop runs in a _filtered range of the worksheet_.

Comment: So I either need to figure out how to use *setValues* to push it to the filtered range, or I need to use *setValue* within the loop... (the latter being less efficient, because each time it writes the same value).